# How to sort serialized JS array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have such output from form with `$("form").serializeArray()`:

```
Answers[0].Id: 16
Answers[0].AnswerText: Go to 2
Answers[0].AnswerLink: 2
Answers[3].Id: 23
Answers[3].AnswerText: Go to 4
Answers[3].AnswerLink: 4
Answers[7].Id: 28
Answers[7].AnswerText: Go to 3
Answers[7].AnswerLink: 3
```

Everything that is before : is name, after : is value
How to convert it to sorted array, like:

```
Answers[0].Id: 16
Answers[0].AnswerText: Go to 2
Answers[0].AnswerLink: 2
Answers[1].Id: 23
Answers[1].AnswerText: Go to 4
Answers[1].AnswerLink: 4
Answers[2].Id: 28
Answers[2].AnswerText: Go to 3
Answers[2].AnswerLink: 3
```

with javascript / jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just normalize your indexes, then you could create new array and then do something like

```js
const newArray = [];
serializedArray.forEach((item) => newArray.push(item));
return newArray;
```

Or, another way is to just pass it through an "always true" filter, like:

```js
serializedArray.filter(()=>true);
```

Comment: Just FYI the [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method is more appropriate for this than `forEach()`/`push()`